# PHP gettext stopped working

Tags: php, gettext

I am on Ubuntu running Apache. The problem (not working) occurs on my production Strato webserver.

My PHP has gettext support, but it does not translate anything, although the strings are translated in the `.mo` file.

This is my code:

```
if (function_exists('bindtextdomain')) {
    $domain = 'address_db';
    echo putenv('LC_MESSAGES='.$lang);
    echo '<br />';
    echo setlocale(LC_MESSAGES, $lang);
    echo '<br />';
    $path = bindtextdomain($domain, "../locale/");
    echo $path;
    echo '<br />';
    echo file_exists($path.'/'.$lang.'/LC_MESSAGES/'.$domain.'.mo') ? 'yes' : 'no';
    echo '<br />';
    echo bind_textdomain_codeset($domain, "iso-8859-1");
    echo '<br />';
    echo textdomain($domain);
    echo '<br />';

    $available_languages = array(
        array('de_DE', _('German')),
        array('en', _('English')),
        array('nl', _('Dutch')),
        array('tr', _('Turkish'))
    );

    echo _('Cancer');
}
```

The output is kind of promising:

```
1

/home/mu/Branches/address_db/locale
yes
iso-8859-1
address_db
Cancer
```

So it finds the file, but it still does not translate "Cancer".

What could that be?

---

## Update

It works on my production server, but not on my testing server. Very strange …

Answer (score 2):

Gettext translations are cached, you need to restart your server for it to pickup changes to .mo files.

Answer (score 0):

It looks as if `setlocale` is returning false, it should return the new locale name if it worked correctly.

Is the value of `$lang` present in the output of `locale -a`? A common mistake is using e.g. de_DE rather than de_DE.utf8 or de_DE.iso88591 in your case.

Comment: I use `de_DE`. It does not change apparently: `Lang: de_DE.iso88591 Setlocale: `. Restarting Apache did not change. Other browser does not work either.